# I have 3 lines in a `.txt` file each line containing 3 numbers and I want to `+1` to them numbers depending on the user input

Tags: python

So basically I have a file with 3 lines and each line has 3 numbers

```
7,2,1
10,0,0
2,8,0
```

Then depending on the user input I want to +1 to one of the numbers on the line.

```
if user_input == 1
     +1 to line1Number1
elif user_input == 2 
     +1 to line1Number2
elif user_input == 3
     +1 to line1Number3
else 
    print"error"
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read over [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I would like to append the txt file so it changes the number accordingly.

Comment: You mean add +1 to each number on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(filename, "r") as txtr:
    data = txtr.readlines()
data = [x.split(",") for x in data]
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):
        data[i][j] = int(data[i][j])
```

data now has 3 lists with 3 numbers each.

```
if user_input == 1
    data[0] = [x+1 for x in data[0]]
```

just do the same for the rest.

to save to text file:

```
ndata = [",".join(x) for x in data]
nndata = "\n".join(ndata)
with open(filename, "w") as txtw:
    txtw.write(nndata)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
In [1634]: user_input = int(input()) 

In [1627]: with open('t.txt', 'r') as f: 
      ...:     lines = f.readlines() 

      ...: for c,l in enumerate(lines): 
      ...:     if c == user_input: 
      ...:         lst = l.split(',') 
      ...:         lst = [int(x) + 1 for x in lst] 
      ...:         print(lst)

[3, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this (explanation in comment). Reads from in.txt, write to out.txt.

```
# ask user input for which column to update
update_column = int(input("Column to update 1,2 or 3?"))
# open file to read from
with open("in.txt", "r") as f:
    # for every line in the text file
    for line in f.readlines():
        # make the numbers into an integer list (remove new line, split by comma, and convert to int)
        new_line = list(map(int, line.strip().split(",")))
        # add one to the number in the column input 
        new_line[update_column -1] +=1
        # open a file for a pending
        with open("out.txt", "a") as of:
            # append the list removing brackets and adding a new line
            of.write(str(new_line).replace("[","").replace("]","") + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I now have another problem. I had to add names of teams infront of the scores. so the txt now looks like this 'MAN U 6,0,0 LIVERPOOL 8,0,1 CITY,4,0,2'. So now i cant change the line to INT. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @snkrhype You need a few lines of code to do that. If the in.txt file formated TEAMNAME 0,0,0 then this will do (>> is a new line)         >> team_name = line.split(" ")[0]
        >> scores = line.split(" ")[1]
        >> new_line = list(map(int, scores.strip().split(",")))
        >> new_line[update_column -1] +=1
        >> new_line = f'{team_name} {new_line}'

Comment: @snkrhype place the code above between (    for line in f.readlines():) and (        with open("out.txt", "a") as of:)